# WIFI not recognized by Ubuntu with pre installed Win8 (12.10)

Tags: 12.10, wireless, windows-8

I recently installed 12.04 (and currently upgrading to 12.10) onto my computer so I could dual boot win8, via bootable flash drive. After much frustration, I finally got ubuntu to work, but it will not recognize the wireless driver. When I type in iwconfig it shows I have no etho and lo connection. I can however connect to the internet via a wired connection.

so, I tried installing the bcm via synaptic and that didn't do anything. I uninstalled and reinstalled..still nothing. I tried using the "additional drivers" on settings to no avail. So, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ndiswrapper

`sudo aptitude install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-modules-1.9 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9`

Install the WiFi driver (from Windows):

`sudo ndiswrapper -i yourdriver.inf`

Check the driver is working:

`sudo ndiswrapper -l`

Load the module:

`sudo depmod -a`

`sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`

Configure modprobe so that it loads ndiswrapper:

`sudo ndiswrapper -m`

Edit the modules to add ndiswrapper at the end:

`sudo gedit /etc/modules`

Remember to add ndiswrapper at the end.

Hope you now have your WiFi back!